# Issue with MongoDB, Node and Express-looking up ID in Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am currently working on a simple MEAN project and I am working on pulling one item out of my mongo db and show it on the web page. Whenever I go to the site 
http://localhost:3000/api/events/5782b1dbb530152d0940a227 to see the information on the object, I get null displayed. I am, like I said, suppose to see information on this object. Here is what my code looks like:

controllers:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Eve = mongoose.model('Info');

var sendJSONresponse = function(res, status, content) {
res.status(status);
res.json(content);
};

module.exports.eventsReadOne = function(req, res) {
 Eve
  .findById(req.params.eventid)
  .exec(function(err, info){
     sendJSONresponse(res, 200, info)
   });
  //sendJSONresponse(res, 200, {"status" : "success"});
 };
```

Models:

```
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' )

var eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  activity: String,
  address: String,
});

mongoose.model('Info', eventSchema);
```

routes:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var ctrlEvents = require('../controllers/events');

//events
router.get('/events/:eventid', ctrlEvents.eventsReadOne);

module.exports = router;
```

Now, one thing that may be noticed is that I call my mongo collection events. However, I forgot that event is a key word in JS so I tried "changing" it to Info which you will see on the last line of my model. Like I said, if I go to the site http://localhost:3000/api/events/5782b1dbb530152d0940a227, where the last number is the obj _id then I should see all of the data on it. Instead, all that I see is null. Any help would be great, thank you!

my other model file, db.js, has the connection:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost/mission';
mongoose.connect(dbURI)

require('./events');
```

Comment: Care doing `console.log(req.params)` ?

Comment: Yes, nothing seemed to happen, I placed it right above the sendJSONresponse, any ideas?

Comment: `event` isn't a keyword in JS. Try adding some error handling. Also, I assume that you're calling `mongoose.connect()` somewhere in your code?

Comment: You need to check the output in console. Just check if req.params has any value.

Comment: I am calling mongoose.connect() in another file, added it above, I am not sure if req.params has a value since I am not showing anything.

Comment: So to recap: your model is called `Info` but your collection is called `events`, right?

Comment: With all respect, `.findById(req.params.eventid)` here you use the `req.params.*` and if it at all is empty, I don't think it would work. You need to fix req.params.eventid first.

Comment: @robertklep, my Model is called mission and the collection is called events, I attempted to change the name to info for a stupid reason! But have changed it back to mission but node crashes telling me: MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "mission".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose will use the model name to determine which MongoDB collection it should use. The default scheme is to take the model name, lowercase and pluralize it, and use the result as the collection name, which in your case (using `Info` as model name) would be `infos`:

```
// This is where the model is created from the schema, and at this point
// the collection name is decided.
mongoose.model('Info', eventSchema);
```

If you want it to use a different collection, you have to explicitly tell Mongoose what collection to use by setting the [`collection`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection) option for your schema:

```
var eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  activity : String,
  address  : String,
}, { collection : 'events' });
```

To fix the error you're stating in the comments (*Schema hasn't been registered for model "mission"*), you need to make sure that you change all occurrences of `mongoose.model()`:

```
// To create the model:
mongoose.model('Mission', eventSchema);

// Later on, to access the created model from another part of your code:
var Eve = mongoose.model('Mission');
```

(although it seems to be that "mission" is the name of your *database*; because your collection is called *events* I would think that a model name `Event` seems much more appropriate)

Comment: awesome! You got it man! It works! Thank you for helping this person starting out with the MEAN Stack!